# How to subscribe to multiple variables from an Angular service

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to get started using Angular and TypeScript.

So far I have managed so send a request to an API and render the response

I'm subscribing the `content` to the response, how can I subscribe the variable `content_to_render` at the same time?

```
import {Injectable, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class NodeService implements OnInit {
    constructor(private http:Http){
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.loadContent();
    }

    private content;
    private content_to_render;

    loadContent(node_id = 59) {
        this.http.get('/ez/ezpnode.'+node_id+'.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
            contentData => this.content = contentData,
            err => console.error("Error occurred: ", err)
        );
    } 
}
```

Comment: If I understood your question well, you want to setting the value of `content_to_render` in the `subscribe` *function* also, is it right? If so, just wrap it with `{}`:  `contentData => { this.content = contentData; this.content_to_render = 'blabla'; }`

Comment: thanks @developer033, please post this as an answer so I can mark this question as resolved

Comment: Hey, @user3531149 I just posted it as answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question well, you also want to set the value of `content_to_render` in the subscribe function also, is it right?

If so, just wrap it with `{}`. The braces let you add multiple statements inside the block, as below:

```
contentData => { 
  this.content = contentData; 
  this.content_to_render = 'blabla'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide some background on what you are trying to accomplish?

I don't normally subscribe in my service. Nor do I load the content on the initialization of the service.

My service method looks like this:

```
getMovie(id: number): Observable<IMovie> {
    const url = `${this.moviesUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get(url)
        .map((res: Response) => {
            const body = res.json();
            return <IMovie>body.data || {};
        })
        .do(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I then subscribe in the component that uses this service:

```
getMovie(id: number) {
    this.movieService.getMovie(id)
        .subscribe(
            (movie: IMovie) => this.movie = movie,
            (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

I have a complete example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing

Or a simpler example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-GettingStarted

Answer (score 0):

You can also return an Observable an subscrive to get the info you want when you need it:

```
private content;
private content_to_render;

private load(node_id:number): Observable<any> {
    this.http.get('/ez/ezpnode.'+node_id+'.json').map(res => res.json());
}
private loadContent(): void {
   this.load(51).subscribe(
        contentData => this.content = contentData,
        err => console.error("Error occurred: ", err)
    )
}
private loadAnotherContent(): void {
   this.load(51).subscribe(
        contentData => this.content_to_render= contentData,
        err => console.error("Error occurred: ", err)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, all you would need to do is:

```
loadContent(node_id = 59) {
    this.http.get('/ez/ezpnode.'+node_id+'.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
        contentData => { 
            this.content = contentData;
            this.content_to_render = contentData;
        },
        err => console.error("Error occurred: ", err)
    );
}
```

With this being said, the other answers raise good points about the use of services and observables.

Comment: I think you didn't see that developer033 already stated this in the comment section. It'd be polite to ask to provide it as an answer rather than to plagiarize it like your own answer (in case you missed it disregard my comment)

Comment: You're correct that I missed developer033's comment. And I agree with your point regarding if I had seen it. Thanks for the note.